# Make vertical scrollbar add width to div instead of compressing contents

Tags: html, vertical-scrolling, css

I am trying to get a scrollbar that will be invisible when not needed, but that will not squish the contents when it is needed. `auto` interacts with `text-overflow: ellipsis` in a bad way, such that even when the text does not overflow the `max-width`, the longest lines are ellipsis'ed.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zchx5/1/

`overflow-y: auto` squishes the contents and makes the ellipses appear when the scrollbar appears. `overflow-y: scroll` does not have that problem, but the scrollbar is always visible. The scrollbar makes the `div` wider instead of taking up space inside the div and squashing the text.

How can I have the advantages  of `overflow: auto` without squishing the text and getting undesired ellipses when the scrollbar appears? I really want to avoid Javascript so please no scripts.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eZZLa/ Not a tested cross-browser solution, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

text-ellipsis behavior will show up since it bumps in its parent in order to grow it untill it reaches max-width.

To avoid it , you can check width of parent and trigger it to child via a class once max-width is reached.

Basicly, via jQuery , you can do such thing :

```
var empixel = $("hr.gabari");
    $("div.better").each(

    function () {

        if ($(this).innerWidth() > empixel.innerWidth()) {
            $(this).addClass("ellipsis");
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zchx5/9/

Comment: Not quite. As I said in my question, "even when the text does not overflow the `max-width`, the longest lines have ellipses". I want the ellipses when the text overflows the max-width. The way it is now, they always show when the vertical scrollbar shows.

Comment: white-space:prewrap could help i guess

Comment: I cannot have wrapping in the divs so it has to be `nowrap`.

Comment: hmmm, what about to use an extra container in between box and content on which you would hide the scroll bar . http://jsfiddle.net/Zchx5/6/ if that's not what you look for, then i totally do not understand what you try to do  :)

Comment: That's closer, but the scrollbar is always invisible. It should be visible when the content overflows the `max-height`, invisible otherwise, and when it is visible, it should not cause the text to have ellipses **unless** the text is overflowing the `max-width`. Make sense?

Comment: re, yes , then maybe you should use display:inline-block instead absolute with a padding-right to leave room for the scrollbar , test this http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zLGHc hr can be hidden

Comment: Well I have to position it absolutely. But even if I didn't see how in your example that you just posted, how the wide line has ellipses? It has them no matter how little horizontal content you put in div. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: answer updated to trigger ellipsis if needed via jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I you want a scroll bar that appears when ITS NEEDED. And if your dont mind jquery you can use slim scroll. Its really really simple to use and im sure it will add what you need

[Check it here](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)

Here is an example of slimscroll code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DivIDThatYouWantScrollOn').slimScroll({ height: '200px' });
     });
```

Hope you can use it this because its solves it really easy

Comment: If I use this in this one place I'll have to use it everywhere, so it'll have to be a last resort. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: no problem at all, its a very handy "last option" solution solver:)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue recently, just out of curiosity I dived into this problem and found the reason why this issue is occurring.

In your example only, you can observe that with vertical scrollbar width of the div is 227.33px, you can check this using inspect element of chrome, and without scrollbar width of the div is 244.313. So when vertical scrollbar appears in the div, area in which text can appear in the div becomes smaller in size and hence to you it seems that even though the width of the div is sufficient to contain that much text then why it is elapsing the text. Actually, the area in which text can be written in the div becomes smaller i.e. of size “width of div” – “width of vertical scrollbar”.

When you set overflow-y=scroll, width of the div with and without scrollbar is same and hence it is  not elapsing the text inside div.
When you set overflow-y=auto, text able area of the div becomes smaller with scrollbar and without scrollbar area becomes same as actual width*height of div and hence it is  elapsing the text inside div with vertical scrollbar and not elapsing without scrollbar.

So to solve this issue, you can set tooltip on hover OR you can increase the width by some pixels. But as such it is not a problem of text-overflow:ellipsis feature. Ellipsis checks width of the area in which text can be written and compares it with the width of the text to be written.